# Finding n such that f n is maximized in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am using Project Euler problems to learn Haskell and I find a recurring theme in many of these problems where I need to find a value `n` that gives some property (usually minimum or maximum) to a function `f n`. As I build up a solution, I often find it convenient to create a list of pairs `(n, f n)`. This helps me quickly see if I have any errors in my logic because I can check against the examples given in the problem statement. Then I "filter" out the single pair that gives the solution. My solution to problem 47 is an example:

```
-- Problem 47

import Data.List
import ProjectEuler

main = do
    print (fst (head (filter (\(n, ds) -> (all (==consecutiveCount) ds)) 
                       (zip ns (map (map length) 
                                    (map (map primeDivisors) consecutives))))))
    where consecutiveCount = 4
          consecutive n start = take n [start..]
          consecutives = map (consecutive consecutiveCount) ns
          ns = [1..]
```

It seems to me that there's a more "haskelly" way to do this. Is there?

Comment: A minor improvement: `map f (map g xs)` can be rewritten `map (f . g) xs`. This gives you `map (map length . map primeDivisors) consecutives`, and then you can apply the same trick again: `map (map (length . primeDivisors)) consecutives`

Answer (score 6):

Use `maximumBy` from `Data.List` with `comparing` from `Data.Ord`, e.g.

```
maximumBy (comparing snd) [(n, f n) | n <- ns]
```

this will compute `f` once for each `n`. If `f` is cheap to compute, you can go with the simpler

```
maximumBy (comparing f) ns
```

Comment: hmm you could vectorize this then use data parallel haskell!

Comment: Thanks! I will check this out in more detail when I have some more time. Until then, I'll hold off on accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could write your function as

```
main = print $ fst $ head 
         [ (x,ds) | x <- [1..]
                  , let ds=map primeDivisors [x..x+3], all ((==4).length) ds]
```

You could consider it "more Haskelly" to use `Control.Arrow`'s `(&&&)`, or "fan-out"

```
   filter (all ((==4).length).snd) 
          . map (id &&& (\x-> map primeDivisors [x..x+3])) $ [1..]
```

To be able to tweak the code to try the simple examples first, you'd usually make it a function, abstracting over the variable(s) of interest, like so:

```
test n m = [ x | x <- [1..], all (==n) $ map (length.primeDivisors) [x..x+m-1]]
```

to search for `m` consequitive numbers each having `n` distinct prime factors. There is actually no need to carry the factorizations along in the final code.